# Abstract database access

Tags: c#, sql, xamarin

Let's say I have 2 models in my application and I want a table for each of them but my CRUD operations are the same for both. Is there a way to abstract the table name so I don't have to write the same code for both.

Exemple

```
    class User{
      int id,
      int name,
      int age
    }

   class Seller: User{
      List<string> products
    }
```

and i would access data like this

```
    public static async Task<List<User>> GetAll()
        {
            await Init();

            var users = await db.Table<User>().ToListAsync();

            return users;
        }

     public static async Task<List<Seller>> GetAll()
        {
            await Init();

            var users = await db.Table<Seller>().ToListAsync();

            return users;
        }
```

is there a way to write in abstract for

```
public static async Task<List<T>> GetAll()
        {
            await Init();

            var users = await db.Table<T>().ToListAsync();

            return users;
        }
```

EDIT
I tried with this function

```
public static async Task<T> GetUser<T>(int id, bool isCustomer)
        {
            await Init();

            return await db.Table<T>().Where(x => x.id == id).FirstAsync();

        }
```

Errors:
'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'SQLiteAsyncConnection.Table()'

'T' does not contain a definition for 'id' and no accessible extension method 'id' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: have you tried this to see if it works?

Comment: Are the two models using the same Context (db)?  If not then it should be GetAll(Context db)

Comment: @jdweng tables are in the same database, yes

Comment: I would expect `GetAll<T>` to work, it should be easy enough to test

Comment: Same problem.. "T must be non abstract"

Comment: It is not the database that is the issue.  It is the context.  You can have multiple Context for same database.  The Context is a mapping between the database and classes.  If both models use the same mapping than you code will work.  It the two models use two different mappings (two dbContext) than it will not work.

Comment: db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);               This is how i declare my db connection and from here i access the tables. Isn't the same?

Comment: add a `where` constraint to `T` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this if the classes implement the same interface e.g.

```
interface IDataRecord
{
  //record index
  int Id{get;set;}

  //deep clone/copy function
  object Clone();  
}

public abstract class BaseRecord<T> : IDataRecord
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        var newRecord = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        var props = newRecord.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(p => p.CanRead);
        foreach (var p in props) p.SetValue(newRecord, p.GetValue(this));

        return newRecord;
    }
}

class User : BaseRecord<User>
{
  [NotNull]
  string Name{get;set;}

}
```

then you could have something like (redacted from my code but essence is there)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the base class upon which all data tables shall be based.
    /// </summary>
    public class AccessDataTableBaseSqLite<T> :  where T: IDataRecord, new()
    {
        public static SQLiteAsyncConnection DBConnection;

        /// <summary>
        /// Lock object to prevent multi-thread interruption of code segment.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly object CollisionLock = new object();

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public AllAccessDataTableBaseSqLite()
        {
            lock (CollisionLock)
            {
                if (DBConnection != null)
                {
                    DBConnection.CreateTableAsync<T>().Wait();

                    return;
                }

                try
                {
                    string directory;

                    if (DeviceInfo.Platform != DevicePlatform.Unknown)
                    {
                        directory = FileSystem.AppDataDirectory;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        directory = "DataStore";
                        var directoryInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
                        directory = directoryInfo.FullName;
                    }

                    var path = Path.Combine(directory, $"{typeof(T).Name}.db");
                    if (!File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        using var fileStream = File.Create(path);

                        fileStream.Close();
                    }

                    DBConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);
                    DBConnection.CreateTableAsync<T>().Wait();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (ex is UnauthorizedAccessException)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create the data table
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task<CreateTableResult> CreateTableAsync()
        {
            if (DBConnection != null)
            {
                return await DBConnection.CreateTableAsync<T>();
            }

            return CreateTableResult.Migrated;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new record entry
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity">Data entity to enter</param>
        /// <param name="user">Current User information</param>
        /// <returns>New entry record if successful</returns>
        public async Task<T> CreateAsync(T entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            if (DBConnection == null)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            entity.Id = 0;
            try
            {
                await DBConnection.InsertAsync(entity);

            }
            catch (SQLiteException e)
            {
                if (e.Message == "Constraint")
                {
                    throw new InvalidConstraintException(e.Message, e.InnerException);
                }
            }            
            var result = entity;

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Update a collection of new entities of type T to the data table.
        /// All entities should be present within the data table
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entityList">Entity collection</param>
        /// <returns>ID of entities successfully updated or added</returns>
        public async Task<int> UpdateAllAsync(IEnumerable<T> entityList)
        {
            var result = 0;
            foreach (var t in entityList)
            {
                if (null != await UpdateAsync(t))
                {
                    result++ ;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Obtain the data record with the given Id
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">Id value to select the record by</param>
        /// <returns>A valid record if found otherwise null</returns>
        public async Task<T> GetById(int id)
        {
            if (DBConnection == null)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            return await DBConnection.Table<T>().Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function returns all database entries that are not marked deleted or changed
        /// Warning: The data set may be very large
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A list of entries</returns>
        public async Task<List<T>> GetAll()
        {
            if (DBConnection != null)
            {
                return await DBConnection.Table<T>().ToListAsync();

            }
            return new List<T>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function is used to update the supplied record entry within the database.
        /// If the supplied record does not have a non-zero value Id field it is assumed to be a
        /// new record to be inserted into the database.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity">Record to update</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task<T> UpdateAsync(T entity)
        {
            if (DBConnection == null)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            if (entity == null)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            var newRecord = (T) ((entity) as BaseRecord<T>)?.Clone();

            if (null == newRecord)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            //if Id is zero assume that the record is new and to be added
            if (newRecord.Id == 0)
            {
                newRecord.Id = await DBConnection.InsertAsync(newRecord);
                return newRecord;
            }

            // Id is not zero and thus a new record should be created linked to the old record.
            var oldRecord = await GetById(newRecord.Id);
            try
            {
                var result = await DBConnection.UpdateAsync(oldRecord);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

               Debug.WriteLine($"UpdateAsync {e.Message}");
            }           
            
            newRecord.PreviousRecordId = oldRecord.Id;
            newRecord.Id = 0;
            
            return await CreateAsync(newRecord);

        }

        public async Task<int> DeleteAsync(T entity)
        {
            if (DBConnection == null)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            return await DBConnection.DeleteAsync(entity);
        }

        public async Task DeleteAll()
        {
            await DBConnection.DropTableAsync<T>();
            await CreateTableAsync();
        }

        public async Task<PagedResult<T>> GetAllPagedResult(int recordId, uint maxResults = 100)
        {
            if (DBConnection == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            List<T> list;
            
            if (maxResults == 0)
            {
                list = await GetAll();
            }
            else
            {
                list = await DBConnection.Table<T>().Where(x => (x.Id >= recordId)).ToListAsync();
                if (list.Count() > maxResults)
                {
                    list = list.GetRange(0, (int) maxResults);
                }
            }

            return new PagedResult<T>(list, list.Count());

        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> FindAsyncOrdered<TValue>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null,
            Expression<Func<T, TValue>> orderBy = null)
        {
            var query = DBConnection.Table<T>();
            if (predicate != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(predicate);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                query = query.OrderBy<TValue>(orderBy);
            }

            return await query.ToListAsync();
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public async Task<T> FindFirst(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) => await DBConnection.FindAsync(predicate);
    }
```