# How do I share common code with .NET Core dependency

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

My question is with using dependency injection in .NET Core I am able to create different repositories for some of the CRUD operations and expose it to API. However by doing this the way I have below I end up with lots of repeated code as I have to create new methods for Add, Update & Delete for each class. How can I accomplish this but by having common code for this, since the only things really changing are the entities and what table is used. You can also see same code at [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZFAX3P).

I removed as much non essential code as I could...

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public interface IBaseDao
{
    Task SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public interface ICrudRepository<TModel, TId> : IBaseDao
{
    public Task<TModel> AddAsync(TModel model, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    public Task<TModel> UpdateAsync(TModel model, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    public Task DeleteAsync(TId id, string userName, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public interface IPersonCrudRepository : ICrudRepository<Person, int>
{
}

public abstract class BaseDao : IBaseDao
{
    protected BaseDao(CustomDbContext dbContext) =>
        this.CustomDbContext = dbContext;

    protected CustomDbContext CustomDbContext { get; set; }

    public virtual async Task SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
        _ = await this.CustomDbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public class CustomDbContext : DbContext
{
    public CustomDbContext(DbContextOptions<CustomDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}

public class PersonCrudRepository : BaseDao, IPersonCrudRepository
{
    public PersonCrudRepository(CustomDbContext dbContext)
        : base(dbContext)
    {
    }

    public async Task<Person> AddAsync(Person model, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(model);

        var entity = (await this.CustomDbContext
            .Set<Person>()
            .AddAsync(model, cancellationToken)
            .ConfigureAwait(false)).Entity;

        await this.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return entity;
    }

    public async Task DeleteAsync(int id, string userName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var entity = new Person { Id = id };
        _ = this.CustomDbContext.Set<Person>().Attach(entity);
        entity.ModifiedBy = userName;
        entity.StatusId = (byte)Status.Inactive;

        await this.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public async Task<Person> UpdateAsync(Person model, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(model);

        _ = this.CustomDbContext.Set<Person>().Attach(model);
        await this.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return model;
    }
}

public class Person : ChangeTracker
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
}

public abstract class ChangeTracker
{
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public byte StatusId { get; set; }
}

public enum Status
{
    Active = 1,
    Inactive = 2,
}

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
    }

    public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) =>
        _ = services.AddScoped<IPersonCrudRepository, PersonCrudRepository>();
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about a generic abstract class? when i was working with dapper i just solve it that way, other approach would be extension methods

Comment: Does the answer at this link help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68273081/abstract-database-access/68273797#68273797

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something generic ->

//create a generic interface

```
    public interface IBaseRepository<T>
    {
        public IQueryable<T> GetAll();
        public T? GetById(Guid id);
        public Task<T?> GetByIdAsync(Guid id);
        public IQueryable<T> GetByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
        public void Create(T entity);
        public Task CreateAsync(T entity);
        public void Update(T entity);
        public void Delete(T entity);
        public void Save();
        public Task SaveAsync();
    }
```

//create a generic abstract class

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly CustomDbContext _dbContext;

    protected BaseRepository(CustomDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll() => _dbContext.Set<T>().AsNoTracking();
    public T? GetById(Guid id) => _dbContext.Set<T>().Find(id);
    public async Task<T?> GetByIdAsync(Guid id) => await _dbContext.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
    public IQueryable<T> GetByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) => _dbContext.Set<T>().Where(expression);
    public void Create(T entity) => _dbContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    public async Task CreateAsync(T entity) => await _dbContext.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
    public void Update(T entity) => _dbContext.Set<T>().Update(entity);
    public void Delete(T entity) => _dbContext.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    public void Save() => _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    public async Task SaveAsync() => await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

//create your repository interface

```
public interface IExampleRepository : IBaseRepository<ExampleEntityClass>
{
}
```

//create your concrete repository class

```
public class Repository : BaseRepository<ExampleEntityClass>, IExampleRepository 
{
    public Repository (CustomDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: i think this a nice solution, i would modify the methods and declare them as virtual, just in case any of them need an alternative implementation

Comment: This was the right answer for my needs. I shared my changes at [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XmFkSy)